# For $x\in [0,1]$, what is the maximal value of the following function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $x\in [0,1]$, what is the maximal value of the following function

$$\max_{x\in [0,1]}c_1x^{-1}\exp(-c_2 x^{-1})$$

I just plot the graph of $x^{-1}\exp(-1/x)$ as follows:

[image]

So it seems that the maximal value is obtained as $x=1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to find critical point(s) by calculating the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{c_1e^{-\frac{c_2}{x}}}{x}\right) = 
-\frac{c_1(x-c_2)e^{-\frac{c_2}{x}}}{x^3} \overset{!}{=}0\qquad \text{only at}\ x=c_2$$
So if $c_2>1$ the maximum value is at $x=1 \to c_1e^{-c_2}$
and for $c_2<1$ it's at $x=c_2 \to \frac{c_1}{c_2e}.$